# How to accomplish complex Laravel query with counts

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a model relationship that looks like this in semi-pseudocode (hope it makes sense)

```
Member ->hasMany(Sessions)

Session -> hasMany(Purchases)

Session -> hasMany(PageViews)
```

Both Purchases and PageViews `belongTo` a `session`, and that `session`belongTo`a`member`.

I need to write either an eloquent or raw query to get totals for the number of sessions, the total value of purchases (purchases.cost) and the number of pageViews within a certain date period that belong to each member.

Example, Between Dec 01, 2017 and Dec 31, 2017, member(id) 9999 had 10 sessions and within those 10 sessions he made 2 purchases for a total value of $1000 and he also had 20 pageViews.

```
 Member  |  Sessions  |  Total Value  |  Page Views
---------------------------------------------------
  9999  |    10      |     $1,000    |      20
```

Can this even be done all in eloquent ? 
Should I be basing my query on the Member table, or the Session table ?
If I use the Member table, how do I actually query the `session.created_at` ?

I tried to start with some raw sql and am having trouble with the count `(Unknown column 'count(sessions.created_at)' in 'field list')` of the sessions, this is what I have so far (`$dates[]` is simply a start and end date:

```
$this->builder = (DB::table('members')
            ->select('members.member_num as member', 'count(sessions.created_at) as sessionCount')
            ->join('sessions', 'sessions.member_id', '=', 'members.id')
            ->where('sessions.created_at', '>=', $dates[0])
            ->where('sessions.created_at', '<', $dates[1])
            ->orderBy('sessions.created_at', 'desc')
            ->groupBy('sessions.created_at')
            ->groupBy('members.member_num'));
```

When I tried this select portion instead

```
->select('members.member_num as member', 'sessions.created_at as session_date')
```

The query works, but obviously I don't get the count of sessions I'm trying to do.

I then tried this

```
->select('members.member_num as member', DB::raw('count(sessions.id) as sessionCount'))
```

This time I get a count, but its only 1, when I expect 2 using my test data.

I thought I could also use an API resource to loop through all the relationships and count everything that way, but not sure what is most efficient, or if even possible.

UPDATE:

This is what I've come up with currently (must be a tricky one since no responses yet )

```
$this->builder = (DB::table('sessions')
            ->join('members', 'sessions.member_id', '=', 'members.id')
            ->select(
                DB::raw('members.member_num as member'), 
                DB::raw('count(sessions.id) as sessionCount'), 
            )
            ->where('sessions.created_at', '>=', $dates[0])
            ->where('sessions.created_at', '<', $dates[1])
            ->groupBy('member'));
```

OK so that's great - step 1 works, it gives me the count value I expect, however when I start adding on joins and more counts of other columns, the counts start to multiply, so with my test data, the above gives me a sessionCount of 2 - good!

When I do this, the sessionCount becomes 4 (same test data)!  Not good!

```
$this->builder = (DB::table('sessions')
            ->join('members', 'sessions.member_id', '=', 'members.id')
            ->join('posts', 'sessions.id', '=', 'posts.session_id')
            ->join('purchases', 'sessions.id', '=', 'purchases.session_id')
            ->select(
                DB::raw('members.member_num as member'), 
                DB::raw('count(sessions.id) as sessionCount'),
                DB::raw('count(posts.id) as postCount'),
                DB::raw('sum(purchases.total_cost) as total_value')
            )
            ->where('sessions.created_at', '>=', $dates[0])
            ->where('sessions.created_at', '<', $dates[1])
            ->groupBy('member'));
```

Why?? :(